# Python Pexpect spawn object Flush

Tags: python, linux, pipe, pexpect

I have a script where i am creating a spawn object using pexpect.

The code looks like this:

```
self.rshcmd='rsh 192.X.X.X'
self.pipe1 = pexpect.spawn(command=self.rshcmd, logfile=sys.stdout,maxread=512)
```

Now after I get into this, I expect for prompt which I get is `>`

And now I become su by sending `su` and then giving the password. Now my prompt as expected becomes `#`

I have a router connected to this spawned PC (192.X.X.X) which is `192.168.1.1`

I telnet into this router by sending `telnet 192.168.1.1`. After I am done from this router, I want to get out of the telnet session.

So I send in `exit` and expect for `#` as I will get back to the the root of the spawned PC. But what I see is that I am actually getting `<` as my prompt.

So somehow it is sending "exit" twice . One takes me out from telnet and other one takes me out from being root. I think the pipe is not flushed out and we get he some old stacked commands being sent.

Is there a way i can flush out all the older commands in the pipe?

From the documentation there is a flush function, but it seems to do nothing:

```
flush(self)
    This does nothing. It is here to support the interface for a
    File-like object.
```

Comment: pexpect does not send the commands twice. Could the telnet connection be closing itself before you send `exit`?

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
child.send(cmd)
child.pexpect(cmd)
child.send('\n')
```

instead of

```
child.sendline(cmd)
```

This will solve your problem.
(but when sending password do child.sendline(passwrd) )